# PHP Berkeley DB vs array

Tags: php, database, database-performance, berkeley-db

I need to store about 500 000 key=>value pairs at server. I see two ways to store them in Berkeley DB or directly in php array. Could you tell me which way is better?

Comment: That many key/value pairs in a PHP array is a h*** of a lot of memory overhead that needs allocating/deallocating on every request - if you don't want to use a database, then use a proper key/value store like redis or memcache

Comment: I want access them by key just as in assoc array

Comment: You can access them by key using a key/value store..... that's what key/value stores do

Comment: But you can't expect to hold 500,000 items in a straight PHP array without it causing you severe memory and performance problems

Comment: I suggest you read [this article](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) about memory and PHP arrays (by one of the PHP core developers), and then work out how much memory you'd need for an array with 500,000 key/value pairs